# Java generics, add all ints/vectors in a list

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning generics in Java from C++ and am confused how to do math without operator overloading. Say I want to write a `sumList` class that's just a list with a sum method.

```
public class sumList<T extends CanAdd<T>> {
    private List<T> list;

    public sumList() {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void addElement(T t) {
        list.add(t);
    }

    public T getSum() {
        T ans = null;
        for (T t : list) {
            if (ans == null) {
                ans = t;
            } else {
                ans = ans.plus(t);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

and the interface I'm using is simply:

```
public interface CanAdd<T>
{
    // returns a new T that's the sum of the object + other
    public T plus(T other);
}
```

So this is simple enough when I create `sumList`s of classes I create, a `Vector` or a `Point` for example, because I can add the plus method defined by the interface. However, how would I change `sumList` so that I can also create `sumList<Double>` or `sumList<Integer>`?

Edits: Fixed minor mistakes.

Comment: But what is it about what you already have that prevents you from instantiating `sumList<Double>` and `sumList<Integer>`?

Comment: @Kirk: Neither `Integer` nor `Double` implement `canAdd`.

Comment: I think you have a bug there: Shouldn't it be `ans = ans.plus(t);` instead of `ans = ans.add(t);`?

Comment: @Niklas, ah, right, I didn't realize that's what the OP was getting at.

Comment: @NiklasB. oops, you're right, edited

Comment: OP, there's _not_ going to be a cute way of doing this in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kaleb said, if you only need this to work with Java Numbers then you should not worry about an interface and simply use T extends Number.

But if you really want to make this more generic and use your canAdd interface, then you need to write a wrapper class around the Number object and use that instead.

**EDIT**

Maybe you are looking at it the wrong way. Instead of having the classes that populate your list have a specific behaviour (in this case the sum), you should instead borrow some useful tricks from Functional programming.

You can write map, reduce and filter methods in Java. You have some boilerplate to get you to the point where you can use them but then you can easily create a reduce function for every type of object you want to sum and then apply that to your list.

Comment: "Wrapper class" sounds like a lot of overkill... Java is one of the few languages where this is actually a hard task :/

Comment: what you basically want is extension methods. Something java does not provide out of the box. Hopefully in a future version, who knows. For the moment you might want to look at Aspect Oriented Programming frameworks that provide extension methods. but that would be more of an overkill for your use case.

Comment: @Sawas: I like the suggestion to take a more generic folding function, but it doesn't answer the question. The question is how to write an algorithm that performs summation on either built-in numeric types or custom types with user-defined addition. BTW, supplying a callable as an argument to an algorithm is equally painful in Java (anonymous objects etc.).

Comment: well it kinda does. Think about it. If you had method overloading like you do in C-type languages, you would have to write an implementation of the + function for every type of object that you wanted to sum. In my suggestion, you have to do the same but in reverse, instead of the object acquiring the method that adds it to another object, a reduce method does, Same logic, different semantics.

Comment: @Sawas: Yeah, but how can you associated the reduce function with a type?

Comment: well the reduce function will be a generic abstract class that you will need to implement on per type case. Same as you would with overloading the + function. It would have a method called sum(T,T) that would return T. For each type, the implementation of this method would be different

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense since if I had to use any other java class with some method that's not + I'd have to define it like that as well. Just thought there might be something obvious missing since I don't know java generics and this seemed like a problem that'd come up every now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the base class of Double and Integer, Number?

`public class sumList<T extends Number>`

That way, no need to implement a canAdd interface or create wrappers for using Doubles and Integers with that interface.

Edit: but if you really need to make this work for custom classes, I think you'd have to make a wrapper class that provides the necessary canAdd interface.

Or, use a language like Scala or Groovy that gives you access to mixins!

Comment: But how would you use the `sumList` with custom classes like Vectors then?